# Postgres 9.5 and BDR along with RLS

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I am implementing a multi tenant web app using postgres. I want to use Row Level Security (RLS) for data separation. RLS is available from PG version 9.5. However, at the same time, the HA / DR teams plan to use BDR ( Bi directional replication) for the HA solution. It seems that BDR is not yet supported in 9.5.

- What can be done in such a scenario ?
- Is it possible to get BDR on 9.5 ?
- What other replication strategies provide the same benefits as BDR?

Yes, schemas is also an approach, but I am already using that for tables which have less data. I want RLS for tables that will eventually get enormous, so replicating them in different schemas wont be ideal.

Note: Cross posted from dba.stackexchange since no one replied there..